# Mimicking Python behavior for `len` and `bool`

Tags: python, class, built-in

Consider the following code:

```py
>>> class X:
... pass
...
>>> x = X()
>>> len(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'X' has no len()
>>> bool(x)
True
```

But when trying to mimick this writing `__len__` it does not work.

```py
>>> class Y:
...   def __len__(self):
...     raise TypeError
...
>>> y = Y()
>>> len(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __len__
TypeError
>>> bool(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __len__
TypeError
```

Is there a way to write a `__len__` function that works like it is not implemented?

Comment: If you want `bool` to work even with a messed up `__len__`, you can implement `__bool__` as well and have it do whatever you want.

Comment: @interjay An object in python can be `True/False` for many reaons: numbers are true if they are nonzero, containers are true if they are not empty, etc. So `bool` does a lot of checks to determine which one to use. I would like to know if there is an implementaiton of `__len__` that mimicks the not implemented behavior. I raised TypeError because that is what a class without `__len__` implemented does.

Comment: but clearly, the place where you raised TypeError isn't where the error is coming from, otherwise what you see wouldn't have happened. On a hunch, i'd say its the `len` itself responsible for raising it, when there is no `__len__` method.

Comment: Why do you want to write a `__len__` function that works like it is not implemented?

Comment: @Sanyash because I am curious to understand how it works. @paritosh-sing That is also the way I think it works. `bool` checks if the method exists and acts. I was wondering if there is a something to return or raise that works in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bool()` tests the *truth value* of an object, so you want to look at the [rules for *Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a `__bool__()` method that returns `False` or a `__len__()` method that returns zero, when called with the object.

You only implemented a `__len__` method that's deliberately broken, raising `TypeError` when called. But `bool()` *will* call it when there it is an implemention and there are no other options available to determine the truth value.

When determining the truth value, [`__bool__` is preferred over `__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__):

> When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero.

Demo:

```
>>> class Z:
...     def __bool__(self):
...         return True
...     def __len__(self):
...         raise TypeError
...
>>> len(Z())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __len__
TypeError
>>> bool(Z())
True
```

Note that it is the `len()` function implementation that raises `TypeError` when there is no implementation for the `__len__` hook. There is no exception that a `__len__` implementation can raise that'll let you pretent it is not actually implemented, any exceptions it raises are propagated if it is called, because you'd normally would want to know if the implementation is broken in some way.